# How to upload a file in chunks to Google drive?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api

I am making file uploader in google drive and using googleapis library for that. I managed to set up a single file upload, but in order to upload large files I need to use chunk upload. Tried many options, but could not solve the problem.

I need help finding a bug or setting up a Google Drive file upload script using chunks. Files up to 1 mb are loaded correctly. Files loaded by chunks are not fully loaded.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const { google } = require("googleapis");
const { getGoogleClient } = require("../../../utils/google");

async function uploadFile(file) {
  const auth = getGoogleClient();
  const drive = google.drive({
    auth,
    version: "v3",
  });

  const folderId = process.env.GOOGLE_FOLDER_ID;
  const chunkSize = 1024 * 1024; // 1 MB chunks

  const filePath = file.path;
  const fileName = file.name;
  const fileSize = fs.statSync(filePath).size;

  if (fileSize <= chunkSize) {
    // upload single file
    const media = {
      mimeType: file.type,
      body: fs.createReadStream(filePath),
    };

    await drive.files.create({
      requestBody: { name: fileName, parents: [folderId] },
      media,
      supportsAllDrives: true,
    });
  } else {
    // upload file with chuncks
    const res = await drive.files.create(
      {
        requestBody: {
          name: fileName,
          parents: [folderId],
          uploadType: "resumable",
        },
        supportsAllDrives: true,
      },
      {
        headers: {
          "X-Upload-Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
          "X-Upload-Content-Length": fileSize,
          "Content-Type": file.type,
        },
      }
    );

    const fileId = res.data.id;

    let start = 0;
    let end = Math.min(chunkSize, fileSize);
    let chunkIndex = 0;

    while (start !== end) {
      const chunkStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath, {
        start,
        end,
      });

      const headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
        "Content-Length": end - start,
        "Content-Range": `bytes ${start}-${end - 1}/${fileSize}`,
      };

      const updateRes = await drive.files.update(
        {
          fileId,
          media: {
            body: chunkStream,
          },
        },
        {
          headers,
        }
      );

      start = end;
      end = Math.min(start + chunkSize, fileSize);

      console.log(`Updated chunkIndex ${chunkIndex}`, updateRes);

      chunkIndex += 1;
    }
  }

  console.log("Done!", fileName);
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: In your situation, is this official document useful? https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-uploads#resumable

Comment: @Tanaike I used this documentation, but it didn't help. I tried setting up API requests, but it didn't work either.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I used this documentation, but it didn't help. I tried setting up API requests, but it didn't work either.`, I apologize that my comment was not useful for your situation.